# Netbeans 8.0.2 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, netbeans-8, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to connect it to database but theres aa error message that showing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver is it because of my netbeans version? I installed it on Windows 7.

String var1="sample1";
              String var2="jdbc;odbc:"+var1;

```
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection var3=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\Database1.accdb");
        PreparedStatement var4=var3.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('" + jTextField1.getText() +"')");

        var4.execute();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

What should i do? other versions wont work if I installed it just the 8.0.2. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to add the connector to the classpath. It's a .jar file you need and you can find it here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: @ThePerson - That is incorrect.  The missing driver is NOT a JDBC driver.  It is the JDBC/ODBC bridge class ... and it is missing because it was removed from "rt.jar" in Java 8.

Comment: @StephenC Well it is a JDBC driver, but it isn't one that's supplied in a separate JAR file, let alone from the MySQL site.